# Add new html tag into existing component jsf 1.1/1.2 (XPages)

Tags: jsf, xpages, jsf-1.2

There is a standard Pager component which renders below html structure:

```
<div class="xspPagerContainer">
  <div class="xspPagerRight" id="view:_id1:pager1">
    <span class="xspPagerNav xspFirst" id="view:_id1:pager1__First">
      First
    </span>
    <span class="xspPagerNav xspPrevious" id="view:_id1:pager1__Previous">
      Previous
    </span>
    <span class="xspPagerNav xspGroup" id="view:_id1:pager1__Group">
      <span>
        <span class="xspFirstItem xspCurrentItem">
          1
        </span>
        <span>
          <a>2</a>
        </span>
        <span class="xspLastItem">
          <a>3</a>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to add some extra html tags like  into above structure:

```
<div class="xspPagerContainer">
  <div class="xspPagerRight" id="">

    <span id="NewSpan"></span>

    <span class="xspPagerNav xspFirst" id="someId">
      First
    </span>
    <span class="xspPagerNav xspPrevious" id="view:_id1:pager1__Previous">
      Previous
    </span>
```

I was trying to use renderer to do it but I was not able to add anything inside xspPagerContainer div. All I achieved was to add something before or after this div.

Is something like this possible? How can I add html tag to already existing component without javascript (jQuery etc.) ? Should I create own component and create own renderer ?

This is IBM variation of JSF used in Xpages.

Comment: Can you post any of the code from your renderer? The relevant portions would most likely be either in `encodeBegin`, `encodeChildren`, or `buildContents`.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the pager component has facets that you can use to insert content

Comment: Maby take a look at the Artikle from Keith Strickland: http://www.keithstric.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/dx/KSTD-8MGJTA May also help you with your renderer.